# Java jTable compute each row

Tags: java, jtable, rows

can anybody here help me on how to compute rows in jtable?
assuming that i have a table containing fields date, description, aCCount, SCount and lost , i have loaded the four field from database except lost field because i want to compute it on runtime, can anybody help me? here is image attach for clarification

```
public void cha(){
  ArrayList<Chalsim> list = getChalsim();
  DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
  Object[] row = new Object[4];
  for(int i =0; i<list.size(); i++){
      row[0] = list.get(i).getDate();
      row[1] = list.get(i).getDesc();
      row[2] = list.get(i).getAc();
      row[3] = list.get(i).getSc();

      model.addRow(row);
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can extend AbstractTableModel,and then assign it to JTable

```
new AbstractTableModel() {
public String getColumnName(int col) {
    return columnNames[col].toString();
}
public int getRowCount() { return rowData.length; }
public int getColumnCount() { return columnNames.length; }
public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    return rowData[row][col];
}
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
    { return true; }
public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
    rowData[row][col] = value;
    fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
}
```

}

and then put it into JTable

JTable table = new JTable(new MyTableModel());